# How to style mui V5 modal paper with custom style?

Tags: material-ui

I have the following modal that I want to inject custom backdrop style in to it but I ain't getting so far , in mui v4 worked like charm here is quite the hassle

```js
 <Modal
      id='modal'
      open={bool}
      aria-labelledby='modal-modal-title'
      aria-describedby='modal-modal-description'
      disableScrollLock={false}
      sx= {
       zIndex: 10,
       backdropFilter: 'blur(14px)',
       background: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? 'rgba(104, 99, 99, 0.75)' : 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
          }
      >
      // body
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

`sx` prop correct prop to add a custom style but I think you should be passing object inside. [from sx doc example](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/)

```
    <Box
       sx={{
        color: 'success.dark',
        display: 'inline',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        mx: 0.5,
        fontSize: 14,
      }}
    >
      +18.77%
    </Box>
```